# Prove that $ ’⊂ ’⟹ ⊂ B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $M'$ denote the complement of a set $M$.

Prove  by direct proof  that $ ’⊂ ’⟹ ⊂ B$

<strike>lets begin with</strike>[[We will prove that]] $ ’⊂ ’⟹ ⊂ B$

-direct proof:

let's assume ’⊂ ’ then:

Let x be an arbitrary element in  We want to show that x is also in  [[Fullstop. Since]] <strike>if</strike> x is in A therefore is is not in A' [[Fullstop]] <strike>then</strike> because x in not in A' [[comma]] x is not also in B' therefore x is in B

is this proof correct?

Comment: also would like to see the contrapositive proof

Comment: Your proof is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but some of the things are not stated properly.

Suppose $B^c\subset A^c$, then for any element $x\in A$, if $x\notin B$, then $x\in B^c\subset A^c$, that gives a contradiction, as $x$ is an element of $A$.Therefore, $x\in B$.

Hence $A\subset B$

The proof of the contraposition is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4759651/774120.