# prove $A \not\subset B \implies B' \not\subset A'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

prove $A \not\subset B \implies B' \not\subset A'$

lets assume $A \not\subset B $ hence $\exists x \in A,x \not\subset B $
lest say  $x \in B'$ therefore x is not in B:

$$x \not\subset B$$

therefore

$$x \in A \implies x \not\subset A'$$

is this proof correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are abusing the subset symbol. There is a crucial difference between an element membership ($\in$) and a subset containment ($\subset$).

If $A\not\subset B$, then there exists $x\in A\backslash B$, hence $x\notin B$.
Now this particular $x$ belongs to $B^c$, but also, it does not belong to $A^c$ as $x\in A$, hence $B^c$ contains an element that is not in $A^c$

Hence, $B^c\not\subset A^c$.